# Robot Framework: How to clear the text in Textfield

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I want to know that how to remove the text from Textbox. I have did much search from Google but nothing found currently. Please tell me any Keyword which can help me for remove/clean text in field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this also for clear test field..

> driver.findElement(By.id("textfieldid")).sendKeys("");//empty string

or

> Input Text   (your web element  locator )  ${empty}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a Robot to do it.. Just use Selenium.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("username")).clear();
```

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#clear()

Comment: He is probably talking about [Robot Framework](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/) (the keyword-driven selenium wrapper)

Comment: you're probably right @ErkiM. pretty unnecessary to use that when selenium has `#clear()` though :)

Comment: He is not using Robot Framework just for doing this. He asked how to do it in Robot framework. 
Coming to answer Use Keyword Clear Element Text http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Clear%20Element%20Text

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it. [Check here](https://github.com/rtomac/robotframework-selenium2library/blob/master/src/Selenium2Library/keywords/_formelement.py)

```
def input_text(self, locator, text):
    """Types the given `text` into text field identified by `locator`.
       See `introduction` for details about locating elements. """
       self._info("Typing text '%s' into text field '%s'" % (text, locator))
       self._input_text_into_text_field(locator, text)
```

The `Input Text` keyword is calling the

```
_input_text_into_text_field
```

which is anyway sending the clear command:

```
def _input_text_into_text_field(self, locator, text):
    element = self._element_find(locator, True, True)
    element.clear()
    element.send_keys(text)
```

Comment: When i execute the Library i am getting error "ImportError: No module named keywordgroup". @Erki M

Comment: I think that the solution suggested by user @user3283976 should work. That is executing Input Text keyword with empty string. What I was saying is that if you want to clear the text field before sending keys to it, there is no need to do it as the Input Text keyword is already taking care of it.

Comment: Now i am getting error "StaleElementReferenceException" when i use this Input Text    //*[@name='resolution']    Edit.